# how to implement contrast using fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, contrast

I am trying to implement contrast using fabric js. Seems fabric does not support contrast, but i found a link [here](http://www.avoid.org/contrast-and-brightness-plugin-for-fabric-js/)

This is not working. Anyone help me how to achieve contrast using fabric js.

Comment: That plugin looks good. What do you mean that it does not work?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi could you provide a fiddle?
I keep getting this error:

"img.filters.BrightnessContrast is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.7 there is `fabric.Image.filters.Contrast` class:

```
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Contrast({
    contrast: 40
});
```